# Jquery div dissappearing with no reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a menu animation (also with help of other stack overflowers).

I have (hopefully) my final problem. The `div` that I create on the hover of second `ul` disappears when changing the `li`s on the third `ul`. Changing the `li`s on the second `ul` works just fine (background stays there).

I even tried this as you can see on the jsfiddle example.

```
 $(".main-navigation ul ul:nth-child(2) > li:not(ul:nth-child(3))").
```

I tried to isolate any way possible to not react when leaving the third `ul` `li`s, even though the ">" selector should do that. (figured that's where the problem is.)

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/r8vx07ae/13/

Comment: so you're trying to create hover menu ..? maybe I didn't get your intention, but why do you need jquery for this ?

Comment: Because I couldn't make the background (which is behind the menu in special div). As you can see it has specific animation. First comes the background(.sub-nav) and then the ul. And there are also other reasons (i have a small version of the menu as well).

Comment: I don't see why the `:nth-child(2)` bit would make any difference. Both of the inner `ul`s are second children of their parents.

Comment: @David Knipe. Well I just tried everything. No matter what I do doesn't change... You can remove it if you think it bothers. I mean I'm out of options honestly...